# Replace double-double quotes in a String var?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've a String with this value: `Hello ""World""`

I'd like to replace the double-double quotes characters with a single double quote, like this: `Hello "World"`

How can I do that? I use to call the `split().join()` methods, however, I cannot find the correct regular expression which it works.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/""/g, "\"")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a string replace with regex like this:

```
str = str.replace( /\""/g, '"' )
```

Comment: @SergioAriza Please mark Bennett's answer as marked :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it ;-)